# What's the difference between the following ways of definition in JS?

Tags: javascript, function

code block 1:

```
var a = (function(){
    var obj = {a:'1',b:'2'};
    return obj;
})();
console.log(a);
```

code block 2:

```
var a = function(){
    var obj = {a:'1',b:'2'};
    return obj;
}();
console.log(a);
```

I know the results of console.log are the same.But is there any difference during the execution procedure?

Comment: Example one is an immediately invoking function expression. http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/ whereas example 2 is not.

Comment: @Richard Macarthy why not?

Comment: There is no practical difference. Both of them are function expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var a = (function(){
    var obj = {a:'1',b:'2'};
    return obj;
})();
console.log(a);
```

The function is an IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression).

The function will be invoked and the returned value will be assigned to `a`.

In the second expression, Only the syntax differs, but the functionality is same. But as a good practice, it's good to wrap the function within `()`. If you use just below code, it will give error.

```
function(){
    var obj = {a:'1',b:'2'};
    return obj;
}();
```

Whereas

```
(function(){
        var obj = {a:'1',b:'2'};
        return obj;
    }());
```

and

```
(function(){
        var obj = {a:'1',b:'2'};
        return obj;
    })();
```

both won't give error, because we are explicitly defining it to be treated as a expression.

Answer (score 2):

The only effect that putting parenthesis around a function has is to ensure it is treated as a function expression.

Putting it as the RHS of an assignment also has that effect.

Consequently, there is no difference between the two.